# Hiding password for SQL user in Powershell

Tags: sql, powershell, passwords, parameter-passing, credentials

I am using the following script to pass SQL credentials at the command line , but I need user to enter the password for the SQL user not the Windows Credentials in it and to make sure that the password is not revealed in clear text when inserted in the prompt. Here is my script:

```
Param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
  [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
  [string]$dbusername="",
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
  [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
  [string]$password="",
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
  [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
  [string]$Machine=""
  )
```

This works fine, but I would like to make sure that the password is hidden when user is inserting it in the prompt.

I have used this line to do it

```
Read-Host -Prompt "Enter your password" -AsSecureString
```

But this cannot be inserted in the Param block, and I I insert it afterwards it has no effect.

How can I mask the password when is inserted by the user at the prompt?

Comment: if you have PS V3 , casting to securestring ie: `[securestring]$password=""` should be suffisant

Comment: Thank you for your input. If I am changing casting as you mentioned indeed the user is prompted to insert the password as I want, in a "hidden mode" however I am getting authentication errors. Maybe I should mentioned that I am using a function in which I insert the connection string. The function works just fine without the securestring. Do you need the full script to see it?

Comment: `[Parameter(Mandatory)][System.Management.Automation.Credential()][PSCredential]$Credential`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PS V3,casting to securestring ie: `[securestring]$password=""` should be sufficient.
You will certainly have to convert back this securestring to plain text before using it with your app. This can be done with:

```
$Ptr = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToCoTaskMemUnicode($password)
$clearpassword = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringUni($Ptr)
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ZeroFreeCoTaskMemUnicode($Ptr)
```

Comment: using $clearpassword ? can you echo it and verify it ?

Comment: After `Param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
  [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
  [string]$dbusername="",
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
  [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
  [securestring]$password="",
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
  [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
  [string]$Machine=""
   )` I have inserted

Comment: `$Ptr = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToCoTaskMemUnicode($password)
$clearpassword = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringUni($Ptr)
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ZeroFreeCoTaskMemUnicode($Ptr)`

Comment: yes but do you use $clearpasword instead of $password in your connexion string ?

Comment: the password is hidden as I wanted, but I get  `Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "Login failed for user 'A4_reader'."`

Comment: You mean that i should change `$SqlConnectionTEST.ConnectionString = "Server=SQLSERVER1;Database=DATABASE1;uid=$dbusername;pwd=$password"
    $SqlConnectionTEST.Open()` with `$SqlConnectionTEST.ConnectionString = "Server=SQLSERVER1;Database=DATABASE1;uid=$dbusername;pwd=$clearpassword"
    $SqlConnectionTEST.Open()` correct?